# redirection using dup2 command

Tags: c, linux, dup2

I know this is a simple exercise but I'm having troubles with it.

```
 ps | sed 1d | wc -l
```

I am trying to generate an output of the above terminal command using c code for my school exercise. I have written a code that is redirecting all the inputs and outputs to the required destination but I am not getting any output on the console as I haven't redirected the final output in any file so it must be displayed on console.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>  
#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1
int main()
{
   //fd       fd1
//ps | sed 1d | wc -l 
pid_t pid;
pid_t pid1;
pid_t pid2;
int fd[2];
int fd1[2];
pipe(fd);
pipe(fd1);
pid=fork();
if(pid==0)
{                          //redirecting into sed 1d
    close(fd[READ]);
    dup2(fd[WRITE],1);
    close(fd[WRITE]);
    execlp("ps","ps",NULL);
}
else
{
    pid1=fork();
    if(pid1==0)
    {                          //redirecting into wc -l
        close(fd[WRITE]);
        dup2(fd[READ],0);
        close(fd[READ]);
        close(fd1[READ]);
        dup2(fd1[WRITE],1);
        close(fd1[WRITE]);
        execlp("sed","sed","1d",NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        pid2=fork();
        if(pid2==0)
        {                          //must display on console
            close(fd1[WRITE]);
            dup2(fd1[READ],0);
            close(fd1[READ]);
            execlp("wc","wc","-l",NULL);
        }
        
        else
        
        {
            close(fd[READ]);
            close(fd[WRITE]);
            close(fd1[READ]);
            close(fd1[WRITE]);
            wait(NULL);
        }
        
    }
    
}

}
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ps` process has both ends of the `fd1` pipe open, which it shouldn't. Also, the `wc -l` process has both ends of the `fd` pipe open, which it shouldn't. Fix both of those things and your program will stop hanging. Also, `wait(NULL)` only waits for one child process to terminate, not all of them, so you're risking the terminal prompt reappearing before your program is actually done.

Comment: Closing the pipes did fix my problem, thank you!